# Agora Dynamic Key expired, onTokenExpiredDidExpire not firing

Tags: agora.io

I'm setting up authentication with tokens in my app but running into the DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED issue that locked me out of all Agora services.

I produce a new token via the RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid provided in the docs and I'm trying to renew the token but I don't know where to put the renewToken(TOKEN_STRING) function after it has expired.

The client.onTokenExpiredDidExpire watcher is not firing at all and I'm assuming that's the issue but even putting renewToken(TOKEN_STRING) in onFailure callback of client.join I get an error saying I can't call renewToken before the user joins.

Help please!!!!!

Comment: Which Agora SDK are you using? also can you share the code snippet for your `onTokenPrivilegeDidExpire` / `onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire`?

Comment: @Hermes haha, we talked about this on our call ;)

Comment: I didn't realize this was you, hope you got this working

Comment: @bvergara87: running into a similar issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: @HassanBaig I haven't run into this issue since posting my solution, I made it so the token wouldn't expire. Since I generate a new token every time a user joins the channel the expiration doesn't really matter. However, I didn't figure out the issue with the callbacks.

Comment: have you solved anything with renewToken() ?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to make sure your UID in token generation is an integer, string UIDs cause some undefined behavior in the SDK.

Comment: Can you share the code ? How to renew then token in Flutter ?

Comment: I generate uid in integer still this problem is occurring